# AWS CLI not able to load credentials when using Jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, aws-cli

I have EC2 where i have installed AWS CLI using xxxjenkins user. Below are the steps I followed to install awscli:

```
   curl "https://awscli.amazonaws.com/awscli-exe-linux-x86_64.zip" -o "awscliv2.zip"
   unzip awscliv2.zip
   sudo ./aws/install

   which aws
   /usr/local/bin/aws
```

I am able to run awscli commands when i login into the instance.

But when jenkins server SSH into the same instance (for CICD) using same user xxxjenkins and run awscli command I get this error:

> Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Comment: you need to run `aws configure`

Comment: @Amit Baranes i tried this when i login in EC2.But in Jenkinsfile i cannot use "aws configure"

Comment: Do you want to run aws cli commands on ec2 instance from jenkinsfile?

Comment: Yes I want to push images to ECR.So we have added EC2 as jenkins slave.EC2 has proper role assigned

Comment: Do you have an IAM Role assigned to the instance? If so, the credentials will be automatically provided. If not, you will need to login to the instance as the same user than Jenkins is using, then run `aws configure` (or at least create a credentials file in the Jenkins user's home directory).

Comment: @vickey99 I've been having this problem exactly. Do you recall what solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and resolved it by setting up a pipeline on the server for executing the script on the agent. Here are the steps I took:

In the script, include the command `whoami` #foobar to ensure it runs under the correct user.

On the EC2 instance, switch to the desired user using `sudo su - foobar`.

Run `aws configure` to set up the necessary AWS credentials.

After implementing these steps, the script should run smoothly.

TL;DR:
To resolve a similar issue, set up a server pipeline to execute the script on the agent. In the script, use whoami #foobar, switch to the user with sudo su - foobar on EC2, and run aws configure for proper AWS credentials. The script should then run without issues.